# MySql returns different rows with the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm running the next queries:

```
1. select * from page LIMIT 10;

2. select page.id from page LIMIT 10;
```

"id" is the primary key in this table. How it can be possible that MySql returns different rows?

I'm using MySql 8.19

Comment: you can use ORDER BY id LIMIT 10

Comment: I know. But it's very interesting why does it happening in such a way? TY

Comment: Relational databases do not store data sorted, you have to sort it if you want consistent results

Comment: you'll get data based on logical ordering.

Comment: Could you give me, please, a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a link for this, it's just something you learn. The order depends on which indexes the query uses.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of an `order by` clause, row order is arbitrary, but typically whatever is the most convenient for the database engine - often in the order rows are laid out on disk, or whatever rows are in cache memory, etc.

However, for queries that refer only to indexed columns, which would be the case for the `id` column query, databases usually perform an index only scan. Without an `order by` clause, such a scan would typically return rows in the order the *index values* are laid out on disk, not the order the *rows* are laid out on disk. Hence the difference.